# client / login information is wrong when typing wrong client id

Tags: authentication

When typing in my client number on my Bank logging page it tells me that client / login information is wrong when I make a typo . I'm wondering, is this not something that would allow an attacker to easily enumerate users login information and use it for a brute force attack ?

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily.

Your client number may be protected with a checksum. For example, the last digit of your client number might be used to make the sum of all previous digits divisible by 10 without remainder. Most numbers that must often be transfered manually by humans contain a checksum to quickly catch transcription errors.

This will not leak information about existing users, but it will reduce the search space for enumaration of existing client numbers by a factor of ten. If your client number is long enough, this isn't really a problem, though.